# Updating a plot with Matplotlib in the same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to Python (so apologise in advance if what I have is badly put together) and I am trying to make a figure that plots the coordinates as they change extracted from a website on a background image of a map. I have it all up to the point where it plots the coordinates on a map but can't get MatPlotLib to refresh the plot in the same figure. At the moment it just closes and redraws a new figure every 5 seconds. I have tried many different solutions including plt.draw() but can't get it to work with what I currently have.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

----------------------------------------

request = requests.get('url with coordinates')

while request.status_code == 200:

    page = requests.get('url with coordinates')
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    coord = tree.xpath('string(/html/body/text()[30])')

    longlat = coord[13:]

    Longitude = longlat.split(',')[0]
    ['longitude', 'latitude']

    Latitude = longlat.split(', ')[1]
    ['longitude', 'latitude']

-----------------------------------------

    img = plt.imread("backgroundmap.png")
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.imshow(img, extent=[min and max coordinates])
    plt.axis([min and max coordinates])


    plt.plot(Latitude, Longitude , 'ro')
    plt.axis('off')

    plt.show(block=False)

    time.sleep(5)
    plt.close()
```

Is there an easy way to change what I have above to make it re draw the coordinate plot on the same Figure 1 instead of it closing and making a new one? Thank you

Comment: `plt.clf` will clear the figure without closing it. But you might also be interested in using [animations](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.2/gallery/animation/basic_example.html)

Comment: Try putting `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` outside (before) the while loop and try moving `plt.close()` after (outside) the while loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.set_data()` from the `Line2D` object.

Here an example:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
P = ax.plot(range(5),[0,2,8,3,0])
```

Which returns:

[image]

And then you update the data from the plotted line with:

```
P[0].set_data(range(5),[0,1,2,3,4])
```

Which will change the figure to:

[image]